# Guardar valores de usuario en MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una pregunta, estoy haciendo una pequeña página web, la cual va a tener un login, cada usuario va a tener distintos permisos para acceder a diversas páginas y determinadas funciones, el problema es que no encuentro la forma de almacenar dicha información, no sé si usar una columna para cada autorización o solo un campo y ahí guardar en formato JSON todos los valores para cada usuario. Espero me puedan dar una idea de cómo almacenar dicha información.

Comment: Hola Carlos, que lenguaje de programacion vas a utilizar? Debes de crear una tabla de usuarios, con id, nombre usuario, clave y una tabla de grupos de usarios con el id de usuario y grupo al que pertenecen. Pero segun el lenguaje que utilizes deberias de implementar los servicios de seguridad que ofrece el propio el lenguaje en vez de crear el tuyo propio, ya que probablemente dejes fugas de seguridad en tu codigo, que el propio lenguaje por experiencia ya los ha previsto.

Comment: Hola, voy a utilizar PHP para las consultas. Algunos usuarios no podran ver datos personales, otros no podran guardar datos, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Carlos esto es solo un ejemplo valido, puedes ajustarlo a tus necesidades.
Cuando creas un usuario debes de asignarle un grupo.
Puedes crear diferentes grupos de usuarios, segun el grupo que tenga tendra acceso a unos permisos. Despues en tu codigo debes de evaluar el grupo del usuario mediante una consulta a la base de datos para dejarlo acceder o no a ciertas partes del programa. Debes de crear un objeto session y comprobar que el usuario tiene abierta una session. Es decir algo asi:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['name']) && $_SESSION['password'])){

  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("no se ha podido connectar...");
mysql_select_db("nueva");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE USUARIO='".$_SESSION['name']."'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows != 0){ // ES DECIR SI EL USUARIO EXISTE...
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

            $bdusuario = $row['USUARIO'];
            $bdpassword = $row['CLAVE'];

        }
if($_SESSION['name']==$bdusuario){
            if($_SESSION['password']==$bdpassword){//AHORA TIENES QUE COMPROBAR EL PASSWORD
//AHORA DEBES CONSULTAR EL GRUPO DEL USUARIO
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USUARIO_GRUPO WHERE USUARIO='".$_SESSION['name']."'");
//.....
//coloca el resto de tu codigo aqui

include('links.php');
// o mediante includes incluyes la partes a las que va a tener acceso y las que no

}else{

    echo "Acceso no permitido";

}


?>
```

Al codigo anterior debes de agregarle el codigo que gestione mediante condiciones las partes a las que tendra acceso segun el rol o grupo de usuario que tenga.

Esto es un ejemplo de como podria ser tu base de datos:

```
CREATE TABLE `USUARIO` (
  `ID_USUARIO` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `USUARIO` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `CLAVE` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `ONLINE` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

CREATE TABLE `USUARIO_GRUPO` (
  `USUARIO` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `GRUPO` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'USUARIO'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

CREATE TABLE `PERSONA` (
  `ID_PERSONA` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `USUARIO_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NOMBRE` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `APELLIDOS` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `ID_PROVINCIA` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '35',
  `CODIGO_POSTAL` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `TELEFONO` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `ID_IMAGEN` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

CREATE TABLE `POBLACION` (
  `CODIGO_POSTAL` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NOMBRE` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

CREATE TABLE `PROVINCIA` (
  `ID_PROVINCIA` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NOMBRE_PROVINCIA` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

CREATE TABLE `IMAGEN` (
  `ID_IMAGEN` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `MYMETYPE` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `CHARSET` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UTF-8',
  `NOMBRE_ARCHIVO` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `FOTO` mediumblob NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

ALTER TABLE `IMAGEN`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID_IMAGEN`) USING HASH;

ALTER TABLE `PERSONA`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID_PERSONA`),
  ADD KEY `ID_PROVINCIA` (`ID_PROVINCIA`) USING HASH,
  ADD KEY `ID_IMAGEN` (`ID_IMAGEN`) USING HASH,
  ADD KEY `CODIGO_POSTAL` (`CODIGO_POSTAL`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `USUARIO_ID` (`USUARIO_ID`) USING HASH;

ALTER TABLE `POBLACION`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`CODIGO_POSTAL`) USING HASH;

ALTER TABLE `PROVINCIA`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID_PROVINCIA`) USING HASH;

ALTER TABLE `USUARIO`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID_USUARIO`) USING HASH,
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `USUARIO` (`USUARIO`);

ALTER TABLE `USUARIO_GRUPO`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`USUARIO`,`GRUPO`) USING HASH;

ALTER TABLE `IMAGEN`
  MODIFY `ID_IMAGEN` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `PERSONA`
  MODIFY `ID_PERSONA` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `PROVINCIA`
  MODIFY `ID_PROVINCIA` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `USUARIO`
  MODIFY `ID_USUARIO` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `PERSONA`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_PERSONA_IMG` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_IMAGEN`) REFERENCES `IMAGEN` (`ID_IMAGEN`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_PERSONA_POB` FOREIGN KEY (`CODIGO_POSTAL`) REFERENCES `POBLACION` (`CODIGO_POSTAL`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_PERSONA_PROV` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_PROVINCIA`) REFERENCES `PROVINCIA` (`ID_PROVINCIA`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_PERSONA_USU` FOREIGN KEY (`USUARIO_ID`) REFERENCES `USUARIO` (`ID_USUARIO`);

ALTER TABLE `USUARIO_GRUPO`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_USU_GRUP_USU` FOREIGN KEY (`USUARIO`) REFERENCES `USUARIO` (`USUARIO`);
```

Comment: se te agradece la ayuda, pero lo necesario en estos casos es que el OP muestre que avance a tenido así como las dudas que le han surgido pues de lo contrario le estas haciendo todo el trabajo y esa no es la finalidad de SO en español